# how to implement pagination in spring jdbc, in some listing functionality we have logic which merge rows together to form single row?

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-jdbc

Are there open source framework that we can use for pagination, we are considering using Spring JPA for pagination, but then we would have to implement repositories and rewrite our complex SQL queries(Correct me if i am wrong?). We had also considered using caching but we rejected the approach because we don't want in-memory approach. Are there any other pagination framework which we could use, also we have some logic in business layer which might eliminate or merge rows.

Comment: Exisiting Queries maybe complex, but the changes to be made in the query for pagination is Simple.. Never consider about im-memory approach or eliminating rows using business logic as both would make the Server side pagination concept useless..

Comment: Exisiting Queries maybe complex, but the changes to be made in the query for pagination is Simple.. Never consider about in-memory approach or eliminating rows using business logic as both would make the Server side pagination concept useless..